# How to continue configuring packages after a network disruption

Tags: 11.10, updates, update-manager

Today during the normal updating process, I had a temporarily network disconnect. Connection was lost during "configuring packages" (not during download). For some reason the process bar did not show any progress since the network disconnect. (I think it was during configuring flash-plugin and the details showed "wget..."). The the update-manager indicated the network disconnect and quit itself. Now, network is back up again but I guess some packages remain not configured (at least the flash-plugin never finished).

How can I resume the update-process where it stopped or reconfigure the downloaded packages?

Ubuntu 11.10 x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open a terminal and type :

sudo dpkg --configure -a

This should do the trick.